# how to call AAD protected app service Web API using MSI from another app service

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

we have a Asp.net Core Web API deployed as Azure App Service. We enabled MSI on this app service Web API to easily retrieve Keyvalut secrets.

Now we have another app service which will call above web API, and we will enable AAD authentication on the web API.

I know we can register AAD application to allow the second app service to access the Web API, but I am wondering if we can enable MSI on the second app service and use the MSI to get the access token to the web api? 
Any document I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, and you can refer to my article on the subject: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions.

You'll have to define app permissions in your API and then assign those to the MSI service principal through PowerShell or one of the Graph APIs.

Sample app permission in the API's app manifest in AAD:

```
{
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "Read all things",
      "id": "32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Allow the application to read all things as itself.",
      "value": "Things.Read.All"
    }
  ]
}
```

More info on permissions here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad.

You can then assign that to a service principal through AAD PowerShell:

```bsh
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 1606ffaf-7293-4c5b-b971-41ae9122bcfb -Id 32028ccd-3212-4f39-3212-beabd6787d81 -PrincipalId 1606ffaf-7293-4c5b-b971-41ae9122bcfb -ResourceId c3ccaf5a-47d6-4f11-9925-45ec0d833dec
```

The ObjectId and PrincipalId are both the MSI-generated service principal's id. Id is the id of the role/app permission. ResourceId is the id for the API service principal.

After you do this, you can acquire tokens using the managed identity for the API and the token will contain the app permission as `"roles": "Things.Read.All"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I still need to register a AAD application for my Web API. Since the Web API also enabled MSI. Is there a way to define permission on MSI directly without registering AAD application?

Comment: No, you need to register an app for the API.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to googled call API using MSI, seems your blog is only one gave a solid solution:) I didn't find any formal official doc about this solution :(. Could you point me to official documents which your referred to?

Comment: You can see my references for the article at the end. Those however did not discuss this scenario at least at the time. That was the main reason for me writing it.

Comment: Yes, per my googled results, your blog is the only one clearly gave the solution, I did not get any hint from official documents. Really cool writing!

Comment: when trying this solution I get this error when requesting a token running locally on my machine:

 Access token could not be acquired. AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'GUID-HERE' named 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Comment: Locally you may need to configure the app authentication library differently to use a client id + certificate/secret for APIs which you cannot call with the user identity + the app used by the library.